# KeyStroke delay for password text in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, postdelayed

I am developing a windows phone 7 application.

I have requirement where there is a password text box and when user starts typing the letters into the text box, each letter should appear as it is for 1 sec and then get converted to password dot (.).

There should be some delay such that user should be able to see what he has typed for one second and then it should be masked.

In android there is a way  mHandler.postDelayed(new SetPassword(), 1000);

I would like to do it in a similar fashion for Windows Phone 7 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer that runs when the login page comes. With that help u can always delay and display the dots and mask it when ever timer stops.

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior in PasswordBox control to show what the user type for a few moments. You need to set custom delay or you just don't find that control?

Comment: So, is it not possible to do it without timer?

Comment: I want to either have a numeric keypad to passwordbox or be able to set delay to Textbox.